# Change "move windows" shortcuts - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I am trying to change the shortcuts used to move windows while switching workspaces, in Ubuntu 12.04.

The problem is that the shortcuts that I want to use include the combination of Ctrl and W, which closes the window "Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Navigation". So I edited the file ~/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml to modify this entry:

```
<entry name="switch_to_workspace_right" mtime="1416437209" type="string">
    <stringvalue>&lt;Control&gt;&lt;Primary&gt;&lt;Alt&gt;w</stringvalue>
</entry>
```

I only replaced the right arrow by the letter 'w', so now my shortcut for switching to the workspace on the right is "Ctrl+Alt+w".

I now would like to move a window while switching workspace, using "Ctrl+Alt+LeftShift+w" (same as before, with an additional Shift). But then again, I cannot do it through the Navigation window, and this time I do not have any existing code in %gconf.xml that I can modify. I could not find anything about the meaning of mtime, or the global syntax of such an entry.

So my question is: what code should I write in %gconf.xml, or where can I find that piece of information? I am just asking for search assistance, not necessarily for someone to completely solve my problem.

Thank you for any help that you may provide.

Answer (score 0):

`gsettings` is your friend!  ;-)

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case key
```

E.G.:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-1 ['<Control><Alt><Shift><Super><Alt_R>W']
```

makes the current window move to workspace 1 using the above crazy key combination. :-)

```
gsettings --help
```

for more information.